# Regex Expression for Multiple Groups

Tags: r, regex

Text-mining noob here trying to extract out various characters and update a column. I've tried using str_extract but can't seem to get a handle on the regex syntax. Could someone show me please? Thank you!

**Reproducible Data**

```
data.frame("name" = c("D1. Hi my name", "A3.3. Hello this is"), "Amount" = c(1, 4))

        name            Amount
1     D1. Hi my name      1
2 A3.3. Hello this is     4
```

**Expected Output**

```
        name           Amount New Name       Extracted
1     D1. Hi my name      1     Hi my name      D1.
2 A3.3. Hello this is     4    Hello this is    A3.3.
```

Comment: @thelatemail sorry that's my mistake

Answer (score 2):

We can use `extract` from `tidyr`.  Here, we capture by matching the patterns that are not white space (`\\S+`) followed by a space and capture the second set of characters

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 %>% 
    extract(name, into = c("Extracted", "NewName"), "^(\\S+) (.*)", 
             remove = FALSE) %>%
     select(names(df1),NewName, Extracted)
#               name Amount       NewName Extracted
#1      D1. Hi my name      1    Hi my name       D1.
#2 A3.3. Hello this is      4 Hello this is     A3.3.
```

---

Or using `base R`, we can create a delimiter with `sub` and then use `read.csv`

```
cbind(df2, read.csv(text = sub("\\s", ",", df2$name), 
           header = FALSE, col.names = c("Extracted", "NewName")))
```

Comment: sorry @Akrun, there are more spaces behind hence using separate may not work

Comment: @Javier Can you update your example with a new one so that it becomes obvious

Answer (score 1):

Based on the example showed we can extract a letter followed by a number to get `Extracted` and remove the same part to get `New_Name`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(Extracted = str_extract(name, "[A-Z]\\d\\.?\\d?\\."), 
         New_Name = str_remove(name, Extracted))

#                 name Amount Extracted       New_Name
#1      D1. Hi my name      1       D1.     Hi my name
#2 A3.3. Hello this is      4     A3.3.  Hello this is
```

Also this can be integrated into `tidyr::extract`

```
tidyr::extract(df, name, into = c("Extracted", "New_Name"), 
         regex = "([A-Z]\\d\\.?\\d?\\.)(.*)", remove = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be an error in the first answer above.  That answer cannot be duplicated using Jupyter Lab without first converting the data into a tibble.

The original data that was provided is:

```
> data.frame("name" = c("D1. Hi my name", "A3.3. Hello this is"),
> "Amount" = c(1, 4))
```

That answer above shows:

```
> df %>%   mutate(Extracted = str_extract(name, "[A-Z]\\d\\.?\\d?\\."), 
>          New_Name = str_remove(name, "[A-Z]\\d\\.?\\d?\\."))
```

But the mutate function with the regex as shown here generates an error and does not provide the requested output unless the df is first converted to a tibble.

A solution which can be replicated in Jupyter and which does provide the requested output follows:

```
> df <- tibble("name" = c("D1. Hi my name", "A3.3. Hello this is"),
> > "Amount" = c(1, 4))
```

Once a tibble, the mutate and the regex will perform and provide the requested output.

```
>                  A tibble: 2 × 4
> <chr>                <dbl>      <chr>       <chr>
> name                 Amount     Extracted   New_Name   
> D1.Hi my name        1          D1.         Hi my name  
> A3.3. Hello this is  4          A3.3.       Hello this is
```